# Drupal Views Automatic Filter

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-views

I was just wondering if there was a super quick way to automatically add a filtering system into Drupal views.

I.e. I just need to add in the top of my view search by name (text box) and search by category (drop down box)

Or do I just manually create this form then use the filter agruments within the edit view screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

It's part of the Views Module under filters - then you just expose them, simple...

Not sure what Daniel was on about?

Comment: LOL, have you read my answer? the second line "However, when you create a view you can 'expose' the filters you use" ;P
I suggested VBO becose sometimes grants more control on the filters ;)

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand exactly you question, but have you tryed [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)?

However, when you create a view you can 'expose' the filters you use, so the user can change it in the view page.

Comment: I have a view which lists a series of businesses.. I want my front end users to be able to search for businesses either by name or category.